# ASM and registers

Tags: assembly, cpu-registers

I just have a question because I'm learning ASM languages at my school and I don't understand something:

```
(BX)=0100H
MOV AX,BX
```

The address of the source (BX) is empty before the `mov` statement and I don't understand why. My idea is, that it's because there is nothing in BX. Is that true ?

It's Intel syntax.

Comment: Move from register BX to register AX

Comment: "Address of the source"? Better grab some *real* guide/book and read it all.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on the context.  Does bx contain a pointer or a value?  What is the surrounding code?

```
lea     bx, somestring  ; abc
mov     ax, bx          ; ax contains pointer to abc
mov     ax, [bx]        ; ax will contain ba
```

Comment: yes bx contains a value. Am I right if I say that register don't have an adress ?

Comment: Technically, registers have an address.  All a register is, is a sliver of memory on the CPU Die.  E*X, can hold 32 bits of data, be it 4 ASCII characters, an address, or DWORD value.  In your case *x can contain 16 bits of data.

Comment: @Yumino You can't access a register via an address. As such, registers do *not* have an address. The `technically` part that Gunner mentioned is an implementation detail that mostly shouldn't concern you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are moving the value `0100h` directly to the bx register.

To take what's in the location 0100h you'll need to specify it as a pointer to a value (of size) at address.

`mov    bx,WORD PTR ds:0x100` for word size

`mov    bl,BYTE PTR ds:0x100` for byte size